# Re-acquired move-constructibility after inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, move, move-constructor

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class base
{
public:

    base(const base &) = default;
    base(base &&) = delete;
};

class daughter : public base
{
};

int main()
{
    std :: cout << std :: is_move_constructible <daughter> :: value << std :: endl;
}
```

I've been staring at it all morning, but I just can't figure out why it outputs:

```
1
```

Class `base` is explicitly not move constructible (`is_move_constructible` is actually `false` on `base`), and `daughter` inherits from it. Why should it magically become move constructible again? What would the default move constructor of `daughter` even look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Class base is explicitly not move constructible

But it is. That type trait merely checks that `daughter d2( std::move(d1) );` is well-formed for any two objects. You may have explicitly deleted the move c'tor in `base`, but in `daughter` it's only implicitly deleted. So overload resolution will correctly choose the copy c'tor instead.

> **[over.match.funcs]**
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#8) A defaulted move constructor or assignment operator
>   ([class.copy]) that is defined as deleted is excluded from the set of
>   candidate functions in all contexts.

If you *really* want `daughter` to be non-movalbe, you need to explicitly delete the move constructor of `daughter` itself. Then overload resolution will hit an explicitly deleted function, that will make the construct being checked ill-formed.

Comment: What I find curious is that `daughter(daughter &&) = default;` will make the trait false.

Comment: @user2079303 - I think you may have just found a compiler bug. [*"Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions"*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#default-5). That and the paragraph in my answer seem to mean that the declaration you added should not affect the trait.